# Making discord bot mention someone

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

How do I make my bot mention someone on the server?

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'mention',
 description: 'this is a mention command!',
 execute(message) {
  mention = message.mentions.users.first();
  message.channel.send('Hello' + mention);
 },
};
```

I thought it would work but it doesn't. Is there another way to mention someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.mentions.users.first()` returns an object, which is why it's not working. This is the correct way to mention someone:

```js
mention = message.mentions.users.first();
message.channel.send(`Hello <@${mention.id}>`);
```

---

For future reference, here are the formats for all mentions:

```js
'<@{user.id}>' // user mention
'<#{channel.id}>' // channel mention
'<@&{role.id}>' // role mention
'<(a):{emoji.name}:{emoji.id}>' // emote (use 'a' at the front if emote is animated)
```

Comment: Also, what does the '$' do in the statement above?

Comment: Good question - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings