# How to make a discord.js bot say custom messages in a specific channel & tag a user in a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

So, I wanted to create my own discord server for my friends and me, and I wanted it to have some bot features... So I got into coding.. long story short I messed it up and after hours of trying to find the solution I gave up.

The first one is a word filter, works perfectly fine, I just cannot tag anyone.. It's supposed to delete the message that's said and give out a message, just like "@example, don't say that!"

```js
client.on('message', async(msg) => {
    
    if(msg.author.bot) return;
    if(!msg.guild) return;

    var array = ['example1, 'example2'];

    if(!msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')){
        if(array.some(w => ` ${msg.content.toLowerCase()} `.includes(` ${w}`))){
            msg.delete();
            msg.channel.send(`${client.user.tag}`)
            return;
        }
    }
        
});
```

**My second problem:**
I tried creating a command that every time you type in `(prefix)say + "text"` on Discord, the bot will say that message. the best would be if it's possible that you type in all the commands in ONE text-channel and have the ability to choose to what channel I want the bot to type that message too. the simple variant would be fine aswell for me. here is my code:

```js
const isValidCommand = (message, cmdName) => message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + cmdName);

require('dotenv').config();

client.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    else if(isValidCommand(message, "say")) {
        let marketing = message.content.substring(5);
        let marketingchannel = client.channels.cache.get('766732225185054740');
        let logsChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'logs');
        if(logsChannel)
            logsChannel.send(marketing);
    }
});
```

I really hope that I will get it to work..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey you're missing a closing **'** in your first block of code. Right after **example1** and before the **,** in your **array** variable. It should look like:
var array = ['example1', 'example2'];

Answer (score 0):

#### First problem

[`User.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag) doesn't actually mention the user. A user's tag in a combination of their [`username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username) and [`discriminator`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=discriminator).

```js
'Lioness100'; // my username
'4566'; // my discriminator

'Lioness100#4566'; // my tag
```

There are a few ways to mention someone in a message. The first one is the built-in [`Message.reply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) function which will send the given message, prepended with `<mention of author>,`

[image: screenshot]

The second method would be converting the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)/[`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object to a string. Discord will automatically parse it as a mention.

[image: screenshot]

The third and most versatile method would be using mention syntax. For users, it's `<@id>`.

[image: screenshot]

- [All mention syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861647/making-discord-bot-mention-someone/63884255#63884255)

---

#### Your second problem

I'm not quite sure if something is wrong with your code, or what exactly your asking, but I think you want channels to be dynamically chosen per message. You can do this by creating an `args` variable.

```js
// new usage:
// {prefix}say channelName message

client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.author.bot) return;

 // split string by every space => returns an array
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);

 // removes the first element (the command name) and stores it in this variable => returns a string
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 // now it's much easier to check the command
 if (command === 'say') {
  // the first element of `args` is the first word after the command, which can be the channel name
  // we can then find a channel by that name => returns a Channel or undefined
  const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
   (c) => c.name === args[0]
  );

  if (!channel)
   return message.channel.send(`There is no channel with the name ${args[0]}`);

  // join all args besides the first by a space and send it => returns a string
  channel.send(args.slice(1).join(' '));
 }
});
```

- [Learn about command handling](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/)

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It just says that theres no channel defined if I try to type in a channel name and I'm certain I'm doing it incorrectly. Do I have to use quotation marks or..? And my standard prefix is '-' and I told the bot to react to every non-existant command with "sorry, I dont know this command" so always when I type in "say" it tells me that it doesnt know the command.. I wanted to change the prefix for only that command to "?". How do I do that?